# Bit Shifting in Cache Simulation

Tags: c++, caching, memory, simulation

What is the formula for calculating the index and tag bits in

1. Direct Mapped Cache
2. Associative Cache
3. Set Associative Cache

I am currently using this formula for Direct Mapped:

```
#define BLOCK_SHIFT 5;
#define CACHE_SIZE 4096;
int index = (address >> BLOCK_SHIFT) & (CACHE_SIZE-1);
/* in the line above we want the "middle bits" that say where the block goes */
long tag = address >> BLOCK_SHIFT; /* the high order bits are the tag */
```

Please tell me how many bits are shifted in Associative and Set Associative Cache..

Comment: How many "ways" are your associative caches?

Comment: At this beginner level, i am using only 2-way Set associative

Comment: Ok, so if you have an address of some data, and you have "two places" to put the data (instead of one place), how much difference do you think that makes to the shifts? I'm trying to get you to figure it out for yourself, because if I just tell you, you won't learn much.

Comment: @Mats peterssn, i think it depends on the size of cache..

Comment: @MatsPetersson Please tell me, i am searching for this thing for almost 2 days, and nothing i can find more...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think the concrete answer to your question is "zero", but that's simply because you are asking the wrong question.

Right, so a cache with a given size X, that is directly mapped, will simply use the lower part [or some other part(s)] of the address to form the index into the cache. So index is a value between 0 and (chace-size-1). In other words, "address modulo size". Since sizes of caches are nearly always 2<sup>n</sup>, we make use of the fact that both of these can be performed using simple bitwise "and" with (size-1) instead of using divide.

In your code, each cache entry (cache-line) holds a "BLOCK" of 32 bytes, so the address should be divided (shifted) down by the block-size. 2<sup>5</sup> = 32. This shift remains a constant for a constant cache-line size. Since there is no other shift in your example code, I presume you are misunderstanding what you should do.

In a set-associative cache, there are multiple sets of cache-lines that can be used for the same index. So instead of simply taking the lower part of the address as an index, we take a SMALLER part of the lower address. So, the `index = address_of_block & (CACHE_SIZE-1)` should become `address_of_block & ((CACHE_SIZE-1) / ways`. Since we are dealing with a 2<sup>n</sup> number again, we can use the old "shift instead of divide" trick - `x / y` where `y` is 2<sup>n</sup> can be done by `x >> n`.

So, now you just have to figure out what `n` is for your number of ways.

And of course, figure out how you determine which of the ways to use when replacing something in the cache, but that is certainly a completely different question.

Comment: thank you so much for understanding my question deeply and teaching me i such a nice way.

Comment: I have only one question now, if for associative cache i change my formula to index= adddress of block & (CacheSIze-1)/ways

Comment: "ways" are how many "sets" you have in the cache. Obviously, in a fully associative cache (rather than "set associative") there is no index, the whole cache is searched for the correct tag - which is why no modern CPU caches work that way.

Comment: is calculation of tag takes place the same way as index, i.e., int tag = (address >> BLOCK_SHIFT)/ways in associative Mapping

Comment: No, you need the whole tag to be stored - otherwise you'd associate multiple cells with the same address.

Comment: if associativity is held 4, i am dividing the index with 4, It gives the number of hits very low, and misses very high in complete logic.\